# How to make a 3D pivot table in Excel based on day-ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm trying to generate some statistics based on the following input

[image]

I'd like it to come out something like this

[image]

So in other words, generate a pivot table and have it group in some day-ranges, and split in two lines.

So there are two issues here. I can make a pivot table, but I can't make it group in the ranges. After I group it, it never comes up and asks me for the group ranges.

Next issue is to get the two types to split.

I'm using Excel 2010.